# Mock up class object

Tags: design, architecture, unit-testing, mocking

For example I have class `ItemDownloader` which has method `downloadItem`. This method creates instance of another class - `Download` to perform actual downloading.

Question is: I want to test `ItemDownloader` in isolation, so I will probably mock up `Download`. How should I do it?

P.S.: Question is more about design than implementation, I can certainly mock up class object in languages like Smalltalk or Objective-C, or use Prototype pattern in C++. But as I understand there is better solution.

Comment: Does `downloadItem` return an instance of `Download` or uses it internally?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference, but in my situation it uses it internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're talking about Dependency Injection: the act of passing in a dependency to a class that requires it, via a constructor, a property, or a method parameter.

In your case this means not constructing the Download class directly in the ItemDownloader class, but passing it into the ItemDownloader class via the constructor, property or method parameter. You would then mock the Download class and pass the mocked version.

There's plenty of information about DI on the web, [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) for example.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Greg that dependency injection will help solve a lot of your troubles.

Here's a general idea of what your class looks like currently (just a guess):

```cs
public class ItemDownloader {
    public void Download(){
        var download = new Download();
        download.Start(); // Or whatever is done with the downloader
    }
}
```

Now if we were to refactor it to take the download as a dependency (I also used the factory pattern here as I assume you are not reusing your single download object each time the Download method is called) it becomes much easier to test without worrying about the implementation of the actual Download class.

```cs
public class ItemDownloader {
    private DownloadFactory _downloadFactory { get; private set; }

    public ItemDownloader(DownloadFactory downloadFactory) {
        _downloadFactory = downloadFactory;
    }

    public void Download(){
        var download = _downloadFactory.CreateDownload();
        download.Start();
    }
}

public class ItemDownloaderTests {
    public class TestWithMockDownloadFactory(){
        var fake = new Mock<DownloadFactory>();
        /// Logic to setup the fake as needed would go here.
        var systemUnderTest = new ItemDownloader(fake.Object);
    }
}
```